# Pandas set value in dataframe, multithreading - loc vs. set_value

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I'm seeing strange behavior updating a dataframe in a multi-threaded environment. I'm updating cell by cell, using a lock so only one process accesses the dataframe at the same time. It's part of a large application but in a nutshell this is what's going on, where df is a dataframe within a large class (self):

```
def update_data(self, idx):
    self.update_cell(idx, 'a', 0.5*(self.df.at[idx,'b']+self.df.at[idx,'c']))
    print self.df.at[idx,'a']
    print self.df.loc[idx,'a']

def update_cell(self,idx,col,value):
    self.lock.acquire()
    # version 1: self.df.loc[idx,col] = value
    # version 2: self.df.at[idx,col] = value
    # version 3: self.df.set_value(idx,col,value)
    self.lock.release()
```

Now - no matter what version I use, the first print statement works and gives the right value. BUT the second print statement fails (returns pandas.np.nan) in all except version 1. It looks like only version 1 really updates the dataframe.

Thoughts? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: using Pandas 0.17, I no longer get this issue and things work as expected. I believe I was using Pandas 0.14 at the time of my posting the initial question. FWIW, .at is markedly faster than .loc so it ends up being a significant improvement.